# Have problem with iText RTL languages, text separation problem

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have using iText for generating pdf at my project, but the problem is, generated pdf file with text in Arabic printed separated at pdf file.

[image]

And this the code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:\\pdf.pdf"));
        document.open();




        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("D:\\noto-arabic.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font a = new Font(bf,10);


        PdfPTable pdfPTable =new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("سلام",a));
        PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell-12"));
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfCell1);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfCell2);
        PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell-21"));
        pdfCell3.setColspan(2);
        pdfCell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        pdfCell3.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
        pdfCell3.setRotation(90);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfCell3);

        pdfPTable.setWidthPercentage(70);

        pdfWriter.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

        document.add(pdfPTable);
        document.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.open();
}
```

The text should be:

سلام